# Need the PHP query to display the date as MM-DD-YYYY instead of YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php

I  need the PHP query to display the date as MM-DD-YYYY instead of YYYY-MM-DD. Here is my code to retrieve the date, just don’t know how to convert the date format.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tmp ORDER BY photodate ASC'; 
//display results  
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     
    // output data of each row     
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {         
        echo  "<tr class=table-row><td align=center>".$row["photodate"]."<br><center>"."</center><br></td></tr>";
    }     
    echo "</table>"; 
}
else{
     echo "0 results";
  }
arsort($band);
$conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: Sorry, but that code makes my eyes water. Please invest the time to format your code such that it can be read. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it._

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in mysql in the following way:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(photodate, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM tmp ORDER BY photodate ASC
```

Comment: This seems a better approach.

Comment: looks good, but i thought PHP is the better idea. @Samay

Comment: Why do you say so @devpro? I assume its better off to get formatted date from MySQL rather than formatting it in PHP, although there won't be much of difference when it comes to performance.

Comment: @Samay: just because of performance, using function in mysql is a good approach but when really needed, when u can control it by ussing php than no need

Comment: I'd have thought that the formatting really depends on the clients' locale.  i.e. Someone in the United States is likely to want to see a date in the US format, rather than say the UK format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the date_format function. Here is a sample.

```
$date=date_create($row["photodate"]);
echo date_format($date,"m-d-Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = "1993-05-18";
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime($x))
```

**Result:**

```
05-18-1993
```

Check this out on how to correctly format date and time on PHP

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: vote for manual link .

Answer (score 0):

you can try using sql FORMAT() function

check following example

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_format&ss=-1

and change the date format in the query to the one you need